# jQuery check siblings with certain class

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm working on a site that has a weird html formatting. See html below. Basically when a checkbox `.group` is clicked on, All the `.item` checkboxes that follows should get checked  until it hits the next `.groupparent` div. How would approach this. Note: there's also a number inside `<b>` tags that we can also use to count the next `.items` that need to be checked. I appreciate your input. I'm using jQuery.

```
<div class="groupparent"><input type="checkbox" class="group" /><b>3</b></div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="item" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="item" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="item" />
<div class="groupparent"><input type="checkbox" class="group" /><b>2</b></div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="item" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="item" />
<div class="groupparent"><input type="checkbox" class="group" /><b>4</b></div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="item" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="item" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="item" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="item" />
<div class="groupparent"><input type="checkbox" class="group" /><b>6</b></div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="item" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="item" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="item" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="item" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="item" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="item" />
```

Comment: is the class name `groupparent>` a type?

Comment: is class name groupparent or groupparent> ..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming the class name as `groupparent` then I think this will do

```
$(this).parent().nextUntil('.groupparent').filter('.item')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pEZWC/1/)

You can use [jQuery.nextUntil](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) selector here.

Comment: `$(this).parent().nextUntil('.groupparent','.item')` also works.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. The only issue is that filter('.item') is returning an empty array. If i remove filter('.item') i can see everything in between including other html that i don't care about

Comment: @hedhud The fiddle is working fine, do you have any other configuration

Comment: Perfect, just one thing since you already did it, if you check uncheck `.groupparent ` twice or more, it stops working.